# jquery clone function gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, xml-parsing

hi guys need a help here below is my code

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Customers");
            var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
            $.each(customers, function () {
                var customer = $(this);
                $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("fname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("mname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("lname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("qualifier").text());
                $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("alias").text());
                $("td", row).eq(5).html('<a class=1ref href=Default.aspx?id=' + $(this).find("pid").text() + '><i class=icon-zoom-in icon-white></i>View</a>' + '&nbsp;' +
                 '<a class=2ref href=Default.aspx?id=' + $(this).find("pid").text() + '><i class=icon-edit icon-white></i>Edit</a>');
                $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            });
            var pager = xml.find("Pager");
            $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                ActiveCssClass: "current",
                PagerCssClass: "pager",
                PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
            });
```

now i dont have any problem displaying data when the grid has a previous displayed data.
my question is when the gridview doesn't have any data the clone function actually clones the column header not the child rows.

now i tried counting the rows of the grid before cloning to avoid cloning the column header but the result is it wont display the data.

any suggestion would be helpful thank you

Comment: found a solution that is to count the remaining rows if the count returns 1 then it means there are no rows except for the column header then after add some rows using this code $('#GridView1 tbody tr:first').after('<tr><td>new activity<</tr>'); before cloning the rows.thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option when no data is returned is to hide the header using jquery.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        if(customers.length != 0) { 
          //clone here
        }
        else {
          $("#gvCustomers").hide();
        $(".main").html("No data found"); // used class main. Whatever container the     gridiview was in

        }
```

This will hide the gridview header and show it when there is data.

Comment: yeah i also tried it so that when no data is returned il just give the user a notice.thanks